# Inject value from one component to another using service

Tags: angular, service, components, inject

How to inject value from one component to another **using service**?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhynnl - check this one

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service with `Subject`. and subscribe it as observable.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class InjectionService {
    constructor() { }

    private changeSubject = new Subject<any>();

    changeEmitted$ = this.changeSubject.asObservable();

    emitChange(data: {}) {
        this.changeSubject.next(data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about component communication using service than you can try below links.

It is always better to post your tried code or problem code which you want to solve

https://www.dotnetcurry.com/angularjs/1445/angular-services-component-communication

https://medium.com/@enriqueoriol/angular-service-component-communication-4933782af52c

Answer (score 1):

Let consider we have two components child and parent and we will have common service between them that is called the common-data-service.

Common Data Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CommonDataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('Common data service');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

The above code is for creating common service between two components using observable. for observable please go through [this](https://angular.io/guide/observables).

Parent Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonDataService } from "../common-data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    {{message}}
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: CommonDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```

The above code to get the message from the common data service and display on the parent component view.

Child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonDataService } from "../common-data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sibling',
  template: `
    {{ oldMessage }}
    <br>
    {{ newMessage }}
  `,
})
export class SiblingComponent implements OnInit {

  OldMessage:string = "";
  newMessage:string = "";

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => { 
         this.oldMessage = this.newMessage;
         this.newMessage = message; 
    });
    setInterval(
      () => {
        this.newmessage();
      },
      3000
    );
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage(Math.random().toString(36).substring(7));
  }

}
```

The above code is written to update the numeric message every three seconds in the child component. Since the common-data-service is observable, the data in the parent component updated automatically since observable is subscribed in the `ngOnInit` subscribed already.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are looking for a singleton service to share values throughout your app, see here; https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

A quick example using a BehaviourSubject to emit changes to interested components is a follows;

**data.service.ts**

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
    public sharedString = new BehaviourSubject<string>('default value');

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
        // Trigger an update from the DataService every 10 seconds. This could come from an API or open socket
        setTimeout(() => dataService.sharedString.next('DataService 1 says hi'), 10000);
    }
}
```

**comp1.component.ts**

```
Component({  })
export class Comp1Component {
    // Inject data service into Comp1Component
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {

        // Listen to changes
        dataService.sharedString.subscribe((value) => {
            console.log('Comp1Component::: ' + value); 
        });

        // Trigger an update from the Comp1Component every 5 second. This could come from the user UI
        setTimeout(() => dataService.sharedString.next('Component 1 says hi'), 5000);
    }
}
```

**comp2.component.ts**

```
Component({  })
export class Comp2Component {
    // Inject data service into Comp2Component
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {

        // Get the current value
        console.log('Comp2Component::: Current value:: ' + dataService.sharedString.getValue());

        // Listen to changes
        dataService.sharedString.subscribe((value) => {
            console.log('Comp2Component::: ' + value);
        });

        // Trigger an update from the Comp2Component every 1 second. This could come from the user UI
        setTimeout(() => dataService.sharedString.next('Component 2 says hi'), 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This example is injecting service in another service using @Injectable annotation
>
> Account service is injecting logging service using @Injectable() annotation , and 
>      account service is injected in app.component.ts using constructor, also make sure to 
>      add services in providers array in app.module.ts

```
enter code here


 //1. Account Service :

 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { LoggingService } from './logging.service';
    @Injectable()
   export class AccountsService {
     constructor(private loggingService: LoggingService) {}
  }
 // 2. Loggin Service :  
  export class LoggingService {
      logStatusChange(status: string) {
      console.log('A server status changed, new status: ' + status);
     }
   } 
  //3. Add it under providers array in app module 
     providers: [AccountsService, LoggingService],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  //4. Finally app component is injecting account service
      export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      accounts: {name: string, status: string}[] = [];
      constructor(private accountsService: AccountsService) {}
      ngOnInit() {
          this.accounts = this.accountsService.accounts;
        }
     }
```

Comment: How about having a constructor in LoggingService that gets a value which logStatusChange needs? Can I pass paramaters to that Service somehow in AccountService?